# Install modules in other rakudo versions using rakubrew

Tags: raku, rakudo, rakubrew

When upgrading rakudo version using rakubrew, is pretty easy to change versions, but I wnat to know if it is posible to import raku modules from the older version to the new version. doign zef install automatically:

to update:

```
rakubrew build 2020.10
```

but then:

```
❯ raku
Welcome to ™ v2020.10.
Implementing the ™ programming language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2020.10.

You may want to `zef install Readline` or `zef install Linenoise` or use rlwrap for a line editor

To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
```

so I need to install all modules that I currently use:

rakubrew build-zef
zef install Sparrow6
zef install Linenoise

so exists any file .zef or .rakubrew or something that checks to maintain this modules automatically

Answer (score 9):

You can get the list of installed modules using `zef list --installed`. Note you probably want to ignore the `share/perl6` repo, as the `CORE` module included in it is specific to each version of rakudo.

see: https://github.com/ugexe/zef#list-from

> list [*@from]
>
> List known available distributions
>
> $ zef --installed list
>
> ===> Found via /home/nickl/.rakubrew/moar-master/install/share/perl6/site
>
> CSV::Parser:ver<0.1.2>:auth<github:tony-o>
>
> Zef:auth<github:ugexe>
>
> ===> Found via /home/nickl/.rakubrew/moar-master/install/share/perl6
>
> CORE:ver<6.c>:auth<perl>

Alternatively you can use the following one-liner to get a list:

```
$ raku -e 'say $*REPO.repo-chain.grep(CompUnit::Repository::Installation).map(*.installed.Slip).grep(*.defined).map({ CompUnit::Repository::Distribution.new($_).Str }).join(" ")'

Text::Table::Simple:ver<0.0.7>:auth<github:ugexe>:api<> CSV::Parser:ver<0.1.2>:auth<github:tony-o>:api<> CORE:ver<6.d>:auth<perl>:api<>

# $*REPO.repo-chain.grep(CompUnit::Repository::Installation) # Get only repos for installed raku modules
# .map(*.installed.Slip)                                     # Get a list of installed modules for this repo, and Slip it into the outer singular results list
# .grep(*.defined)                                           # Some repos will have had no modules, so remove these undefined entries
# .map({ CompUnit::Repository::Distribution.new($_).Str })   # Use CompUnit::Repository::Distribution to get at the normalized identifier
# .join(" ")                                                 # Join the results together
```

Once you have chosen a way to create a list of what needs to be installed you can just pass that list to `zef` (although your shell may require you to quote names passed in explicitly on the command line)

Answer (score 0):

rakubrew installs different Raku versions in different directories `$HOME/.rakubrew/versions/moar-*`

So each Raku version has its own separate `Installation` repositories ( `site, vendor, ...` ).

And because `zef` installs distributions to `site` repo by default, I think. So the modules are not available under multiple versions.

However, because Raku uses the `home` `Installation` repo (`#inst/home/user-name/.raku`) and it exists in `repo-chain` so you can install the modules you want available on all versions to `home` repo (`~/.raku`). ( the modules will be precompiled the first time `use`ed in a new `Raku` version ).

Please note I haven't tested that with `zef` but I use `Pakku` which installs to `home` repo by default, and the modules I install to `home` are available to all `rakubrew` `Raku` versions on my Linux machine.

Comment: The `home` repo should be avoided for anyone using multiple installations. The repository format is not guaranteed to be backwards compatible, and historically there have been rakudo versions that no longer work once an existing repository has been upgraded by a rakudo install.

Comment: I don't think repository format changes that often, and in the rare cases when that happens, one can install the modules for each Rakudo installation separately in `site` repo. but until it break,  installing to `home` repo one time is easier than installing the modules for every new Rakudo installation.

Comment: If you want to do that, fine. But don't encourage others to do a thing that is something that will break in the future (especially since I presume you are just learning of what I pointed out, and thus have not spent much time considering the ramifications).

Comment: Yes I have been doing that (using `home` repo) for longtime without any issue. And no I'm not encouraging anyone to do something that break their installation. when a new Rakudo version is released, and this new version changes the repo format, this will be mentioned in Rakudo release notes, so before I install this new version I can take care of any issue that might appear.

Comment: I wasn't concerned with how long you've personally been using `home`, but if you understood the ramifications of using it. For instance how you can "fix" an issue that is tied directly to a rakudo implementation detali between versions? Its important to note just because something seems to be working for you doesn't mean you should be doing it. The home repo is for when there is a root installed raku where e.g. `site` is not writable by the user; its not meant to work with multiple raku installs and to suggest to others it is without mentioning the huge caveat is LTA.